# Lubuntu 18 doesn't find Intel WLAN card in ThinkPad P73/nVidia RTX 5000

Tags: lubuntu, thinkpad, iwlwifi

I have a new Windows PC, a [Lenovo ThinkPad P73](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/tp_p73_hmm_en.pdf) with [nVidia RTX 5000](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/pubs/p73/html_en/index.html#t=en%2FConnect_to_an_external_display_(topic)_T0000711680.html%23UsingTheComputerDisplayOrAnExternal-7F460E9F) graphics.

As I got sick of using Windows in the first week, I had to go back to my POSIX environment, So I installed Lubuntu 18 in dual boot.

Now after booting, I am not able to connect by WiFi, as Lubuntu does not find the [Intel(R) Wifi 6](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/wireless/wi-fi-6-ax200-module-brief.html) model [AX200 160MHz adapter](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/189347/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200.html) with Linux support per the [spec sheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/wi-fi-6-ax200-module-brief.pdf).

I have searched and mostly found people providing installation of Realtek drivers.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Congratulations! Awesome machine! Looking for drivers for Linux for you...

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of that. The chip is supported by the iwlwifi driver shipped with kernel starting from 5.1. Since Ubuntu is not a rolling distro, you will have to wait sometime to have this kernel as the main Ubutnu kernel ([the default for 18.04.3 is version 5.0-based](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Updated_Packages)).

Comment: If you want to confirm it'll be fixed by 19.10/18.04.4, you can download the (QA-testing) daily 19.10 from http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/404/builds/  and write to thumb-drive and see if you get wifi there on 5.2.0-15 kernel. If installed it'll be off-topic here until  19.10's release in October, but #ubuntu+1 (the development or next release) has other support options such as IRC  (*navigate to Lubuntu from my prior link, more direct links will be time sensitive as it's recreated daily*)

Comment: Thanks, My issue was fixed after installing iwlwifi drivers.! thanx